# CollectionView.Refresh does not filter

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, collectionview

I'm trying to invoke my filter with out having to re initiate it every time

i.e. 
I want to call

```
myCollectionView.Refresh();
```

instead of

```
myCollectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Filter);
```

The thing is that Refresh has no effect and does not invoke the filter .

Any ideas why this is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [CollectionView.Refresh Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.refresh.aspx) page at MSDN.

> When you set the Filter, SortDescriptions, or GroupDescriptions property; a refresh occurs. You do not have to call the Refresh method immediately after you set one of those properties.

If you *really* want to call `Refresh()` instead of setting the `Filter` property, then you can extend the `CollectionView` class and override the `protected` `RefreshOverride` method to override the behaviour of the method.